# using Dotfuscator with xamarin.forms project ,error 9009

Tags: dotfuscator

trying to protect an android xamarin.forms project after setting all requirement as noted in [PreEmptive Website](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html#setup-choose)
and when i try to build i finished with this error:

The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE" /p:InDir="obj\Release\90\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\90\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 9009.

Comment: Could you increase the [build verbosity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/) to at least "Normal" and rebuild? That should show the textual output of Dotfuscator in the build output. Then please edit your question to include the error message from Dotfuscator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first thanks Joe , after increasing verbosity it was clear in the build output how to solve it :
- in the  of the project file (which i wanted to protect with Dotfuscator) there is a property called   which i set its value to the path of the dotfuscatorCLI file (as per requested by the property name). The simple solution was to add the **CLI file name** to the end of the path and all done without errors.

The old property value was :

```
<DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE</DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>
```

I changed it to :

```
<DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe</DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>
```

The build output that define the problem was as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```